# How to test Google Analytics call with Jasmine after Facebook Like

Tags: facebook, google-analytics, jasmine

I'm new to Jasmine, and I'm experiencing a thorny issue.  I'm trying to verify that a Google Analytics tracking event gets fired after a user "likes" something.

In my code (using the Facebook SDK), when a user "likes" something I trigger a call to Google Analytics like this:

```
       FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(targetUrl) {
            _gaq.push(['_trackSocial', 'facebook', 'like']);
        });
```

That's all dandy, but I don't know how to test this with Jasmine.

From my Jasmine spec, how do I execute a Facebook "like" and then spy on the _gaq.push function to ensure the GA tracking event gets fired?  I'm lost...

Answer (score 1):

Probably,

```
var fbSpy = spyOn(FB.Event, 'subscribe').andCallThrough();
var gaSpy = spyOn(_gaq, 'push').andCallFake(function (args) {
    expect(args[0]).toEqual('_trackSocial');
    expect(args[1]).toEqual('facebook');
    expect(args[2]).toEqual('like');
});

// Trigger here the event.

expect(fbSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
expect(gaSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

Comment: Right, but the problem is triggering the "Like" event in the spec.  Facebook adds its own iframe to the page which is visually displayed as the "Like" button.  Once the "Like" button is clicked, then the Google Analytics tracking code gets fired.  I don't know how to emulate this scenario inside of a jasmine spec.